# Bearer error - invalid_token - The signature key was not found

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular 7 application interfacing with a .Net Core 2.2 API back-end.  This is interfacing with Azure Active Directory.

On the Angular 7 side, it is authenticating properly with AAD and I am getting a valid JWT back as verified on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

On the .Net Core API side I created a simple test API that has `[Authorize]` on it.

When I call this method from Angular, after adding the Bearer token, I am getting (as seen in Chrome Debug Tools, Network tab, "Headers"):

> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
>   signature key was not found"

With a *HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized*.

The simplistic test API is:

```
    [Route("Secure")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Secure() => Ok("Secure works");
```

The Angular calling code is also as simple as I can get it:

```
    let params : any = {
        responseType: 'text',
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        })
    }

    this.http
        .get("https://localhost:5001/api/azureauth/secure", params)
        .subscribe(
            data => { },
            error => { console.error(error); }
        );
```

If I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute and just call this as a standard `GET` request from Angular *it works fine*.

My Startup.cs contains:

```
        services
            .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => this.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

The options are all properly set (such as ClientId, TenantId, etc) in the appsettings.json and `options` here is populating as expected.

Comment: How did you acquire the access token? Sounds like the token *might* be a Microsoft Graph API token.

Comment: @juunas I have an application registered in Azure AD and have a ClientID, TenantID, and app-specific secret that are being passed to the proper endpoints as provided in the Azure management console.  It's a valid JWT.  It looks like this may end up being a conflict with an existing authorization scheme in the application.  Working on that angle.

Comment: Any luck on this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @PatrickI had same issue ? Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same issue. i was missing the authority..make sure authority and api name is correct now this code in configure services in startup file works for me:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication( x =>
                {
                    x.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; //idp address
                    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    x.ApiName = "api2"; //api name
                });
```

Comment: Adding `Authority` saved my day! 
I use `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(x => { x.Authority = "<my_authority>"; })` and it does not work without `Authority`.

Comment: Isn't that using IdentityServer though on top of the JWT Bearer settings?

Answer (score 7):

I had a unique scenario, hopefully this will help someone.

I was building an API which has Windows Negotiate authentication enabled (.NET Core 5.0, running from IIS) and unit testing the API using the `CustomWebApplicationFactory` ([see documentation for CustomWebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) through XUnit which does not support Negotiate authentication.

For the purposes of unit testing, I told `CustomWebApplicationFactory` to use a "UnitTest" environment (`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable) and specifically coded logic into my application Startup.cs file to only add JWT authentication for the "UnitTest" environment.

I came across this error because my Startup.cs configuration did not have the signing key I used to create the token (`IssuerSigningKey` below).

```cs
if (_env.IsEnvironment("UnitTest"))
{
  // for unit testing, use a mocked up JWT auth, so claims can be overridden
  // for testing specific authentication scenarios
  services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer("UnitTestAuth", opt =>
    {
      opt.Audience = "api://local-unit-test";
      opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
      {
        ClockSkew = TokenValidationParameters.DefaultClockSkew,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidAudience = "api://local-unit-test",
        ValidIssuer = "unit-test",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456"))
      };
    });
} else {
  // Negotiate configuration here...
}
```

Regardless of the `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` being `true` or `false`, I still received the "invalid_token" 401 response, same as the OP.  I even tried specifying a custom `IssuerSigningKeyValidator` delegate to always override the result, but did  not have luck with that either.

> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

When I added `IssuerSigningKey` to the `TokenValidationParameters` object (of course matching the key I used when generating the token in my unit test), everything worked as expected.

Comment: Upvote, thanks. Yeah I just had to add IssuerSigningKey and it worked.

Comment: Hi @TimTrewartha and 4e69636b, where did you get the IssuerSigningKey? I'm using Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Hi! I don't remember  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I needed to set the `ValidIssuer` option in the `AddJwtBearer` `TokenValidationParameters`, *in addition to* the authority

For example:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "My Audience";
            options.Authority = "My issuer";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "Also My Issuer",    //Missing line here
                ValidateAudience = true
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

The key when we generate the token:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"));
```

Should be the same on DI:

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be two reason:

1. You might have missed registering service :

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });
```

Or
2. You might have missed assigning value to key "IssuerSigningKey" as shown below

```
validate.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                                        {
                                            ValidateAudience = true,
                                            ValidAudience = "Audience",
                                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                                            ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                                            RequireExpirationTime = false,
                                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghi12345"))

                                        });
```

This resolved my problem

Comment: second one solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My Core API uses different services configuration (and it works :)):

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    Configuration.Bind("JwtBearer", options);
  }
```

Are you sure you are passing an access token and not an *id_token*? Is the `aud` claim present in the token exactly the same as the *clientid* your API is configured with? You may want to add some events to your options to see what you are receiving and where the validation fails.

Comment: Access token is verified fine on jwt.io ... pasting my secret gets me a "Signature Verified".  Decodes properly there.  Perhaps I should switch to trying this with `AddJwtBearer` ... I am using Microsoft's library with `AddAzureADBearer` ... I assume options are the same.  Do you have anything specified other than the default `[Authorize]` attribute on the secure API?

Comment: No, just Authorize. I assume you mean 'pasting the public key', not 'pasting my secret', right? A token may have valid signature but not be for the API - is the aud claim same as what your API expects?

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the values that you send for request the jwt token (eg: grant_type, client_secret, scope, client_id, etc)
2. Ensuere that you are using the appropiate token. That's all!

Here is my mistake:
I was using Postman, and request a token and set it to a varibale "Var_Token1":

```
pm.environment.set("Var_Token1", pm.response.json().access_token);
```

But when I need to use the token for my final request, I selected and use the wrong token (Var_Token2):

```
Authorization: Bearer {{Var_Token2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error was coming because the URL in appsettings.json was incorrect. I fixed it and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if  you are using a different SignedOutCallbackPath/SignUpSignInPolicyId policy id than which is being passed in the token as tfp/acr.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the authority configured in the API must match the authority configured in the client including the http/https.

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue, and it was caused by jwtOptions.Authority not being set in config.

If you are using:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
```

And jwtOptions.Authority is set to null or "" you can get this error message.