# invalid_token -- The signature key was not found

Tags: asp.net, angular, jwt, bearer-token

I am passing token from my UI repo to backend.

```
export class AccountService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,  private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {}
.
.
.
 const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
    };
    debugger;
    return this.http.get<IRetrieveAccountSummaryResponse>(
      AppConfig.settings.businessUrl + '/api/account/AccountSummary/' + loanNumber,
      options
    );
```

In API package,
I have added below code in Startup.cs

```
  services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
           .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
           {
               options.Authority = Configuration[AuthServiceEndpoint];

               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                   ValidateIssuer = false,
                   ValidateAudience = false
               };
           });
            services
                    .AddAuthorization(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Bearer")
                            .Build();
                    });

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

When I try to load page, it gives 401 error. When I checked Network tab, it says

www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

Under Request HEaders, I can see

authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N.......

I am not sure what is incorrect in this case.

[Bearer error - invalid_token - The signature key was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563661/bearer-error-invalid-token-the-signature-key-was-not-found)
It did not help me.