# Entra ID: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, bearer-token, microsoft-entra-id, azure-entra-id

I have configured the entra ID in the Azure portal and in my Web API tenant. I can successfully obtain the access token, but when I use it with my Web API request, I get this error: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found". I checked this token on jwt.io and there seems to be something wrong with the signature part of the token that came to me from Entra ID.

[image: Invalid Signature]

This application in the Azure portal was not created by my own. I tried creating a new one myself and everything works fine. I double checked every setting and everything seems similar.

What could be causing this problem? Could be the problem with Entra ID configuration on azure portal?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rukmini it looks like this one "aud": "api://<client-id>"

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563661/bearer-error-invalid-token-the-signature-key-was-not-found

Comment: invalid signature means you need to add the Azure client id as valid Audience in your tokenValidationParameter.